# Inverting the colorbar with compat=1.18

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am trying to invert the `colorbar` with my own colormap in this figure. (I do not want to change the colors of the dots, just want to flip the colorbar on the right.)
[image]
To define `mycolor` it requires `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}`, but with this option, uncommenting `y dir=reverse` in the code below generates the error:

```
! Use of \pgf@parserestrgb doesn't match its definition.
\pgf@@parsefunc ...shading@model \endcsname [#1; ]
                                                  \ifx \pgf@bounds \pgfutil@...
```

The code is as follows.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\pgfplotsset{
/pgfplots/colormap={mycolor}{
    rgb255(0cm)=(0,0,128)
    rgb255(1cm)=(0,0,255)
    rgb255(3cm)=(0,255,255)
    rgb255(5cm)=(255,255,0)
    rgb255(7cm)=(255,0,0)
    rgb255(8cm)=(128,0,0)
}}

\pgfplotstableread{
y   x   z
90  20  4
80  40  8
70  35  15
85  30  30
61  15  36
74  25  45
70  15  67
59  26  71
55  20  76
}\datatable

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    colorbar,
    colormap name=mycolor,
    colorbar style={
%       y dir=reverse, % generates error
    },
]

\addplot [
    only marks,
    scatter,
    scatter src=\thisrow{z},
] table[x index=1,y index=0] \datatable;

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I am using up-to-date MikTex (installed a month ago) and compiling with 'pdfLaTeX+MakeIndex+BibTeX' on TeXworks on Windows 10.